# SSIS connection Manager property SetValue

Tags: ssis, script-task

I'm trying to use a script task to set the username/password of a httpConnection connection, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Current attempt:

```
httpClient.Properties["ServerUserName"].SetValue(httpClient.Properties["ServerUserName"], "someJunk");
```

This results in an InvalidCastException (Even though said property is a string).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of lack of documentation maybe?
The SetValue function is expecting an `object`, which should be the *same* object it's being called on.

I.e.:

```
httpClient.Properties["ServerUserName"].SetValue(httpClient, "someJunk");
```

Thanks, Reflection!